# Bash: Display Seconds in Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds

Tags: bash, datetime, time, timer, data-conversion

I have a function, inspired by `hms` from [here](https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/hms/), but I wish to extend it to include handling and displaying Days.

I've started editing the script but quickly realised I'm out of my depth with handling the logic with the hours running into days and visa versa...

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

rendertimer(){
    # convert seconds to Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
    # thanks to https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/hms/
    local seconds D H M S MM D_TAG H_TAG M_TAG S_TAG
    seconds=${1:-0}
    S=$((seconds%60))
    MM=$((seconds/60)) # total number of minutes
    M=$((MM%60))
    H=$((MM/60))
    D=$((H/24))

    # set up "x day(s), x hour(s), x minute(s) and x second(s)" format
    [ "$D" -eq "1" ] && D_TAG="day" || D_TAG="days"
    [ "$H" -eq "1" ] && H_TAG="hour" || H_TAG="hours"
    [ "$M" -eq "1" ] && M_TAG="minute" || M_TAG="minutes"
    [ "$S" -eq "1" ] && S_TAG="second" || S_TAG="seconds"
    # logic for handling display
    [ "$D" -gt "0" ] && printf "%d %s " $D "${D_TAG},"
    [ "$H" -gt "0" ] && printf "%d %s " $H "${H_TAG},"
    [ "$seconds" -ge "60" ] && printf "%d %s " $M "${M_TAG} and"
    printf "%d %s\n" $S "${S_TAG}"
}

duration=${1}

howlong="$(rendertimer $duration)"
echo "That took ${howlong} to run."
```

#### Desired output

`349261` seconds: *"That took 4 days, 1 hour, 1 minute and 1 second to run."*

`127932` seconds: *"That took 1 day, 11 hours, 32 minutes and 12 seconds to run."*

`86400` seconds: *"That took 1 day to run."*

#### Actual output

`349261` seconds: *"That took 4 days, 97 hours, 1 minute and 1 second to run."*

`127932` seconds: *"That took 1 day, 35 hours, 32 minutes and 12 seconds to run."*

`86400` seconds: *"That took 1 day, 24 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds to run."*

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BeardOverflow and @NikolaySidorov, this works great:

```
#!/bin/bash

rendertimer(){
    # convert seconds to Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds
    # thanks to Nikolay Sidorov and https://www.shellscript.sh/tips/hms/
    local parts seconds D H M S D_TAG H_TAG M_TAG S_TAG
    seconds=${1:-0}
    # all days
    D=$((seconds / 60 / 60 / 24))
    # all hours
    H=$((seconds / 60 / 60))
    H=$((H % 24))
    # all minutes
    M=$((seconds / 60))
    M=$((M % 60))
    # all seconds
    S=$((seconds % 60))

    # set up "x day(s), x hour(s), x minute(s) and x second(s)" language
    [ "$D" -eq "1" ] && D_TAG="day" || D_TAG="days"
    [ "$H" -eq "1" ] && H_TAG="hour" || H_TAG="hours"
    [ "$M" -eq "1" ] && M_TAG="minute" || M_TAG="minutes"
    [ "$S" -eq "1" ] && S_TAG="second" || S_TAG="seconds"

    # put parts from above that exist into an array for sentence formatting
    parts=()
    [ "$D" -gt "0" ] && parts+=("$D $D_TAG")
    [ "$H" -gt "0" ] && parts+=("$H $H_TAG")
    [ "$M" -gt "0" ] && parts+=("$M $M_TAG")
    [ "$S" -gt "0" ] && parts+=("$S $S_TAG")

    # construct the sentence
    result=""
    lengthofparts=${#parts[@]}
    for (( currentpart = 0; currentpart < lengthofparts; currentpart++ )); do
        result+="${parts[$currentpart]}"
        # if current part is not the last portion of the sentence, append a comma
        [ $currentpart -ne $((lengthofparts-1)) ] && result+=", "
    done
    echo "$result"
}

duration=$1
howlong="$(rendertimer "${duration}")"
echo "That took ${howlong} to run."
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
H=$((MM/60))
D=$((H/24))
```

to

```
H=$((MM/60%24))
D=$((MM/60/24))
```

So, the days are the quotient of your total minutes and the hours are the modulus of your total minutes.

Also, your second example is wrong. The desire output for 127932 is `That took 1 day, 11 hours, 32 minutes and 12 seconds to run`